# cocos2d-x 3.4 プロジェクトを VSC2013 でリリースビルドすると常にフルビルドされてしまう

Tags: cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x ver 3.4（3.5 でも同様）で作成したプロジェクトを、Visual Studio Community 2013 でリリースビルドすると、常にフルビルドされてしまい、ビルドにかなりの時間を要してしまい困っています（デバッグビルドであれば、このような症状は出ない）。
これは何が原因なのでしょうか？
そしてどうしたら、フルビルドでなく、必要な部分のみビルドされるようになるのでしょうか？
ご教授よろしくおねがいします＞原因・対処方法をご存知の方

Answer (score 1):

ソリューションエクスプローラで、libbox2d を右クリックし「プロジェクトのアンロード（L)」を選びます。同様に、libcoco2d, libSpine もアンドードすると、これらが利用不可になり、ビルドを行っても、再ビルドされなくなります。